# jquery lightbox on all pages of asp.net mvc 3 site

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on nopcommerce website 2.65 version which is in mvc. It has couple of layout pages. I need to show a login popup so that user need to enter the username and password before accessing any page on the site. How can I add this popup ( basically jquery lightbox) on all pages ?